# What is the correct way to restrict access to Docker containers to only allow sources on LAN

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to find a way to ensure containers selectively are only accessible from the LAN that the (Linux) docker host is part of. I've seen this question asked/answered on Reddit, Stack, and some random other sites. They simply state when you publish ports to include the localhost address in your compose yaml like:

```
ports:
  - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
```

This makes sense I suppose but after implementing that, this what I see in iptables created by docker:

```
Chain DOCKER (5 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.22.0.2           tcp dpt:8080
```

And when I forward the port on my gateway it can be accessed outside the LAN

I've seen others point to this page that shows how to restrict all containers: https://docker-docs.netlify.app/network/iptables/ but I don't think (?) that option will work for me because I want to selectively control which containers are restricted.

I also see mention of disabling Docker's ability to add rules, but since the docs don't recommend that I'd rather avoid it if possible.

Possibly relevant info: Ubuntu server 22, containers using default (bridge) network mode, ufw is installed/active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for me - from https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker

Modify the UFW configuration file /etc/ufw/after.rules and add the following rules at the end of the file:

```
# BEGIN UFW AND DOCKER
*filter
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-docker-logging-deny - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-user-forward

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 172.16.0.0/12
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN -s 192.168.0.0/16

-A DOCKER-USER -p udp -m udp --sport 53 --dport 1024:65535 -j RETURN

-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 192.168.0.0/16
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -d 172.16.0.0/12
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 192.168.0.0/16
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 10.0.0.0/8
-A DOCKER-USER -j ufw-docker-logging-deny -p udp -m udp --dport 0:32767 -d 172.16.0.0/12

-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN

-A ufw-docker-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW DOCKER BLOCK] "
-A ufw-docker-logging-deny -j DROP

COMMIT
# END UFW AND DOCKER
```

Only difference being that I modified all references to 192.168.0.0/24 to match my LAN. I've done some minor testing and so far it doesn't break the Docker internal networking, it protects containers from the public, and it allows me to use ufw to create rules.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Restrict Internet Access - Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39913757/restrict-internet-access-docker-container)
has accepted this
[answer by Bilal Usean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42336592/165358):

> **Network creation for access internet**
>
> > docker network create --subnet=172.19.0.0/16 internet
>
> **Network creation for block internet access**
>
> > docker network  create --internal --subnet 10.1.1.0/24 no-internet
>
> If you want to connect docker container into internet
>
> ```
> docker network connect internet container-name
> ```
>
> If you want to block internet access
>
> ```
> docker network connect no-internet container-name
> ```
>
> ### Note
>
> in internal network we can't expose ports to connect outside world,
> please refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40059375/5528059) for more details

Comment: I'm not ignoring your answer, I'm now looking at how to test as a Docker compose.

Comment: In my tests the "no-internet" network creates a situation where there is no communication from the host LAN possible, and it ignores published ports. Portainer describes it as "isolated with no inbound/outbound communication"

Comment: There are other answers in the same post which might work better for you.